# How to access LocalStorage from Blazor Server in ServerPrerendered

Tags: jwt, local-storage, blazor, blazor-server-side, bearer-token

So the main issue is how to access LocalStorage or SessionStorage for storing JWT tokens in Blazor Server App with render-mode ServerPrerendered?

As I see everyone is switching the render-mode to Server but we lose the initial prerender and some "better" serving of pages.

So how could this be done mantaining the ServerPrerendered or is there any other way to store the tokens?

Comment: [Here is Microsoft's guide on what to do](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server#handle-prerendering). Have you read it? Basically you just wait for the page to be rendered.